# How to sort HashMap keys when serializing with serde?

Tags: rust, serde

I'm serializing a `HashMap` with serde, like so:

```
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct MyStruct {
    map: HashMap<String, String>
}
```

`HashMap`'s key order is unspecified, and since the hashing is randomized (see [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html)), the keys actually end up coming out in different order between identical runs.

I'd like my `HashMap` to be serialized in sorted (e.g. alphabetical) key order, so that the serialization is deterministic.

I could use a [`BTreeMap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.BTreeMap.html) instead of a `HashMap` to achieve this, as [`BTreeMap::keys()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.BTreeMap.html#method.keys) returns its keys in sorted order, but I'd rather not change my data structure just to accommodate the serialization logic.

How do I tell serde to sort the `HashMap` keys before serializing?

Comment: Note: you may be interested in bluss' [OrderMap](https://github.com/bluss/ordermap), a HashMap whose iteration order solely depends on the order in which elements have been inserted and removed.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use the [`serialize_with` field attribute](https://serde.rs/field-attrs.html#serialize_with):

```
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize, Serializer}; // 1.0.106
use serde_json; // 1.0.52
use std::collections::{BTreeMap, HashMap};

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Default)]
struct MyStruct {
    #[serde(serialize_with = "ordered_map")]
    map: HashMap<String, String>,
}

/// For use with serde's [serialize_with] attribute
fn ordered_map<S, K: Ord + Serialize, V: Serialize>(
    value: &HashMap<K, V>,
    serializer: S,
) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
where
    S: Serializer,
{
    let ordered: BTreeMap<_, _> = value.iter().collect();
    ordered.serialize(serializer)
}

fn main() {
    let mut m = MyStruct::default();
    m.map.insert("gamma".into(), "3".into());
    m.map.insert("alpha".into(), "1".into());
    m.map.insert("beta".into(), "2".into());

    println!("{}", serde_json::to_string_pretty(&m).unwrap());
}
```

Here, I've chosen to just rebuild an entire `BTreeMap` from the `HashMap` and then reuse the existing serialization implementation.

```json
{
  "map": {
    "alpha": "1",
    "beta": "2",
    "gamma": "3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice! There's also an alternative here, relying on `serde_json::Value` using `BTreeMap` internally (which has the advantage of working on a generic `T`, rather than hard-coding the type as `HashMap`): https://stackoverflow.com/a/67792465

Comment: Hmm, for this approach, wouldn't it be better to make the key and value types generic, as with: `fn ordered_map<K: Ord + Serialize, V: Serialize, S: serde::Serializer>(value: &HashMap<K, V>, serializer: S)`?

Comment: @Venryx I wouldn't say _better_, but certainly more widely applicable, sure.

Comment: @Venryx I added a generic implementation to this answer, for the benefit of visitors to this post.

Answer (score 3):

A slightly more generic way with automatic sorting, one that uses [itertools](https://crates.io/crates/itertools), and one that only relies on the std lib.  Try it on [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b2f0a026ae90834e8abbc18f01306ab0)

```rust
// This requires itertools crate
pub fn sorted_map<S: Serializer, K: Serialize + Ord, V: Serialize>(
    value: &HashMap<K, V>,
    serializer: S,
) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error> {
    value
        .iter()
        .sorted_by_key(|v| v.0)
        .collect::<BTreeMap<_, _>>()
        .serialize(serializer)
}

// This only uses std
pub fn sorted_map<S: Serializer, K: Serialize + Ord, V: Serialize>(
    value: &HashMap<K, V>,
    serializer: S,
) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error> {
    let mut items: Vec<(_, _)> = value.iter().collect();
    items.sort_by(|a, b| a.0.cmp(&b.0));
    BTreeMap::from_iter(items).serialize(serializer)
}
```

Both of the above functions can be used with these structs:

```rust
#[derive(Serialize)]
pub struct Obj1 {
    #[serde(serialize_with = "sorted_map")]
    pub table: HashMap<&'static str, i32>,
}

#[derive(Serialize)]
pub struct Obj2 {
    #[serde(serialize_with = "sorted_map")]
    pub table: HashMap<String, i32>,
}
```

Comment: In the std version you collect in to a vec and sort, and then put in a BTreeMap, you only need to do one or the other of these operations. BTreeMap is naturally sorted anyway